# Need previous answer can't solve this to resolve redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: google-oauth

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, https://examrunner.com/googlecallback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/677463899101-20bir5hd06sfoemjibm5qljn6skdr9mm.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=677463899101

```
    'google' => [
    'client_id'     => '677463899101-20bir5hd06sfoemjibm5qljn6skdr9mm.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'client_secret' => '***************',//this is correct is just hidden
    'redirect'      => 'https://examrunner.com/googlecallback',
],
```

Comment: Do you have the URI `https://examrunner.com/googlecallback` set as authorized redirect URI in the Google API console, under "Credentials"? Double check in the link you provided.

Comment: yes i did this but google always showing redirect uri blank

Answer (score 0):

Open the [Google Cloud API console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=677463899101) for your project and select Credentials.

- First, make sure to add the domain to 'Authorized domains'.
  Be sure to click 'Save' at the bottom of the screen.
  [image]
- Next, you can add the URI to the 'Authorized redirect URIs' using the [link](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/677463899101-20bir5hd06sfoemjibm5qljn6skdr9mm.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=677463899101) from the error:
  [image]

Comment: yes i added here but error still remains and also i wait for 24 hrs but nothing happened good

Comment: Finally it is solved i tried to set consent screen and domain verification